# Is this generation of project URL safe?

Tags: php, webserver

In proceedings of [my question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195075/redirection-from-different-path-depths) answer I found a way of generating a project URL regardless of project's path in Document root.

If in a file in the root of the project I define the following:

```
define(PROJECT_URL,
       '//'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].
       substr(__DIR__, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))
);
```

I get a static URL that is useful and will work if I move the project elsewhere.

However because I am fairly novice with web servers and applications I wonder if this approach has any exploitable security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Once defined, how is the `PROJECT_URL` used?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey One use case I found useful was redirection e.g. header('Location: '.PROJECT_URL.'/page.php')

Comment: I do not understand the rest, but I can say that `HTTP_HOST` is safe to use for redirection because it cannot be edited by XSS/CSRF. However, HTTP_HOST is still un-trusted data, and cannot be used to generate a path name to files in your system for download. That circumstance would be called a Path Traversal vulnerability. The answer is basically depending on how you will use it. In summary it is safe to echo back URLs to the client, but not for anything important.

Comment: Most webservers are capable of mapping directories into the url tree from outide the document root (in the case of apache, using the alias and scriptalias directives, mod_userdir and other options). Splitting the __DIR__ based on the length of the documentRoot is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is populated based on the `Host` header sent by the client.  You should probably start worrying at this point, as it's never a great idea to trust data that may be provided by a malicious client.

There is also `SERVER_NAME`, which provides a similar but slightly different result.  You can find some good discussion about these two and the appropriate ways to use them in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1459739/120999).

Now, what attacks could someone perform via manipulation of your hostname?  That depends on your app.  Perhaps you're caching a rendered page and serving it up to another user, and that page was generated with `Host: mymaliciousserver.com`, so now your second user is clicking links to the attacker's server, where they phish out account details.  There are any number of possible vulnerabilities, and rather than trying to patch them all, I'd rather just avoid the problem entirely.

It's also somewhat questionable code anyways - it adds a lot of complexity for something that doesn't change often.  If it's your own custom app, just set the hostname once and be done with it; if it's a distributable app, have the customer set the hostname once and be done with it.  You're adding moving parts and magic, and those tend to have security issues as well as performing poorly in environments you haven't explicitly designed for (e.g. sites behind a reverse proxy, sites hosted on a non-standard port, sites run in a multi-site environment, etc.).